# Trouble running catkin_make run_tests with blacklisted packages

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, ros, catkin

I've been having trouble with catkin_make run_tests with a blacklisting flag, which is unfortunately one of build steps of CI that I need to pass. I am running ubuntu 16.04, ros kinetic. In order to reproduce the issue:

I clone following repo to my workspace: `https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-ros-interface-ethercat.git`

Check out my branch: `F#SRC-2546_new_thumb_calibration_kinetic_devel`

Then, I recursively install all the dependencies from the repository.rosinstall file.

After then, when trying to run through the building process:

catkin_make -> finishes with no errors

catkin_make run_tests -> finishes with no errors

The build step from the CI that I am failing to pass:

```
catkin_make run_tests -DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES="sr_msgs_common;sr_run_trajectories;sr_logging_common;sr_utilities_common;sr_world_generator;sr_watchdog;sr_description_common;sr_description;sr_common;sr_robot_msgs;sr_interpolation;sr_dynamic_time_warping;ros_ethercat_eml;sr_ur_arm_config;sr_config;sr_ethercat_hand_config;ros_ethercat_loop;ros_ethercat_model;ros_ethercat_hardware;ros_ethercat;sr_mechanism_controllers;sr_hardware_interface;sr_hand;sr_gazebo_sim;sr_utilities;sr_mechanism_model;sr_core;sr_tactile_sensors" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=" --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
```

and it fails with

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsr_interpolation collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status sr-ros-interface-ethercat/sr_robot_lib/CMakeFiles/sr_hand_lib.dir/build.make:504: recipe for target '/home/user/workspace/devel/lib/libsr_hand_lib.so' failed
```

I'm really struggling to figure out the issue at this point, especially since the sr_interpolation package compiles correctly and catkin_make and catkin_make run_tests both execute without any issues. Any type of help would be much appreciated.